# How to export a variable withinin a class and function to another component in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, variables, undefined

I have a component named `flow.component.ts` like this:

```
var rsi_result: number[];

@Component({
  selector: 'flow-home',
  templateUrl: './flow.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./flow.component.scss'],
  host: {
    '[@flyInOut]': 'true',
    'style': 'display: block;'
  },
  animations: [
    flyInOut(),
    expand()
  ]
})
export class FlowComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  setRsi(selectedValue){
    console.log('The RSI period is:' , selectedValue);
    periodd = selectedValue;
    this.label2 = ' نام اندیکاتور:  RSI';
    this.label3 = ' دوره زمانی: ' + periodd + 'روزه';
    rsi_result = rsi({period: periodd, values: pricess});
    console.log('The RSI result is:' ,  rsi_result);
  }

}

export const RSI_RESULT = rsi_result;
```

The code works well and I can see the result of this line of code in my console `console.log('The RSI result is:' ,  rsi_result);` but it seems the `export` line out of the class doesn't work and I can't use `RSI_RESULT` in other components and get `undefined RSI_RESULT` error message! Also when I write `rsi_result` or `RSI_RESULT` in console I get the same undefined error!

How is it possible when this line of code `console.log('The RSI result is:' ,  rsi_result);` works well and I can see the `rsi_result` in the console but when I type it by hand I get undefined error message?

EDITL

I tried to create a service named `ngx.service` with this content:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

var RSI_RESULT: number[];
var MACD_RESULT: number[];

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NgxService {

getRsiResult(){ 

  return (RSI_RESULT);
}  

getMacdResult(){ 
  return (MACD_RESULT);

}

  constructor() { }

}
```

Then edited the above code to :

```
export class FlowComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  macd_result: number[];
  rsi_result: number[];
  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog, private ngxService:NgxService) {
  }
  setRsi(selectedValue){
    console.log('The RSI period is:' , selectedValue);
    periodd = selectedValue;
    this.label2 = ' نام اندیکاتور:  RSI';
    this.label3 = ' دوره زمانی: ' + periodd + 'روزه';
    this.rsi_result = rsi({period: periodd, values: pricess});
    console.log('The RSI result is:' ,  this.rsi_result);
  }

}
```

But when I want to use `rsi_result` in the following component named `ngx-charts` I get the same error as before:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {MatDialog, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material';
import { NewsComponent } from '../news/news.component';
import {NgxService} from '../services/ngx.service';
import { Mellat , Khodro, Shepna} from '../shared/stock_inf';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-ngx-charts',
  templateUrl: './ngx-charts.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./ngx-charts.component.scss']
})



export class NgxChartsComponent implements OnInit {

  rsi_result: number[];
  macd_result: number[];

  constructor(public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<NgxChartsComponent> ,
     private ngxService: NgxService) { }

     ngOnInit() {
      this.rsi_result = this.ngxService.getRsiResult(); //.subscribe(RSI_RESULT => this.rsi_result = RSI_RESULT);
      this.macd_result = this.ngxService.getMacdResult(); //.subscribe(MACD_RESULT => this.macd_result = MACD_RESULT);

      console.log(this.rsi_result); 
    }

  // data goes here
public single = [
  {
    "name": " درصد سود",
    "value": 69
  },
  {
    "name": " درصد زیان",
    "value": 31
  },

];


 newArray = Mellat.map((e, i) => ({
  "name": (i + 1).toString(),
  "value": e,
}));

newArray2 = this.rsi_result.map((e, i) => ({
  "name": (i + 1).toString(),
  "value": e,
}));


public multi = [
  {
    "name": "Mellat",
    "series": this.newArray
  },

  {
    "name": "RSI",
    "series": this.newArray2
  }
];

//{name: (i + 1).toString(), value: e.toString()}



  view: any[];

  // options for the chart
  showXAxis = true;
  showYAxis = true;
  gradient = false;
  showLegend = true;
  showXAxisLabel = true;
  xAxisLabel = 'زمان';
  showYAxisLabel = true;
  yAxisLabel = 'قیمت';
  timeline = true;

  colorScheme = {
    domain: ['#5AA454', '#A10A28', '#C7B42C', '#AAAAAA']
  };

  // line, area
  autoScale = true;

  //pie
  showLabels = true;
  explodeSlices = false;
  doughnut = false;


}
```

EDIT2:

I reviewd my code again and noticed that I must delete `var RSI_RESULT: number[];` and `MACD_RESULT: number[];` from my app and also replace `this.rsi_result` lines to `this.ngxService.RSI_RESULT` when my `ngx.service.ts` file looks like this:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable, of} from 'rxjs';



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class NgxService {

RSI_RESULT: number[];
MACD_RESULT: number[];

getRsiResult(){ //: Observable<number[]>{

  return (this.RSI_RESULT);
}  

getMacdResult(){ //: Observable<number[]>{
  return (this.MACD_RESULT);

}

  constructor() { }

}
```

And the program works well by now!

Comment: That's more like it, please delete [the previous attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59812895/3001761). But now the question becomes: why did you think this would work? It's not an `@Component` so the fact that it `implements AfterViewInit` is irrelevant, and either way none of the methods in the class will get called between the end of the class definition and your attempt to export the result.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: How should I fix it?

Comment: I don't know. I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve. Your code doesn't make any sense right now, it's hard to imagine what you were attempting.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: I am trying to pass the `rsi_result` that is calculated in this line of code  `rsi_result = rsi({period: periodd, values: pricess});`  within `setRSI()` method to other components of my program.

Comment: Ok, but that doesn't make any sense. Again, at the point at which you export you've never instantiated the class, let alone called any of its methods. If you want to share something between classes, move it to a *service*: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction.

Comment: I think my `rsi_result` is a global variable. So this line `rsi_result = rsi({period: periodd, values: pricess});` will change it's value, then I can export it with new value in this line of the code: `export const RSI_RESULT = rsi_result;`

Comment: @Hasani That's not how it works, that's not how any of this works ;)

Comment: @PierreDuc: I tried to use services and edited my code, but seems it doesn't work again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo have to put your `share info` in an service and inject that service into all your components.

```
export class FlowComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private readonly myService: MyService){}

  setRsi(selectedValue){
    console.log('The RSI period is:' , selectedValue);
    periodd = selectedValue;
    this.label2 = ' نام اندیکاتور:  RSI';
    this.label3 = ' دوره زمانی: ' + periodd + 'روزه';
    this.myService.setRsi(rsi({period: periodd, values: pricess}));
    console.log('The RSI result is:' ,  rsi_result);
  }

}




// Other file
export class OtherComponent {

  constructor(private readonly myService: MyService){}

  getRsi(){
     return this.myService.getRsi();
   }

}
```

Comment: What is the `getRsi()` inside the `myService`?

Comment: I tried your manner but didn't work! please read the edit part of my question.

Comment: It Worked! Thanks you so much!